# Remove previous versions does not replace DLL's

Tags: visual-studio, installation, dll, windows-installer

I use the extension "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" for creating MSI files in my Windows-Forms-App. The option "RemovePreviousVersions" is activated, it works properly.
V1.0.0 of my project is installed, when i install V1.0.1 then the old version will be removed.

But the used libaries, e.g. EntityFramework.dll or EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll won't be updated.

What can I do?

Many thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to click **Refresh Dependencies** by right-click on the **Detected Dependencies** of the setup project. **Then**, rebuild your setup project.

**Or**, just delete all the **Project Output** and then readd the **Project Output** by right-click on the project-->**Add**-->**Project Output**

Comment: I tried both, but the DLL's from V1.0.0 still remain in the installation folder (C:\Programs (86)\... ), when i install V1.2.0

I don't understand that...

Comment: Please try to set `InstallAllUsers ` to `true`. And rebuild your msi program. You should delete the old dlls under `C:\Programs (86)\...` because it lost the effect. And no program could control it. You should install the old `v.1.0.0` and then then install the new `v1.2.0` to test whether it could overwrite the old one.

Comment: InstallAllUsers is true... I already set it to true at the beginning. Unfortunenately this does not solve the problem. Manual deleting of the DLL's is no option, lot of people have it installed...

Comment: Does `EntityFramework.dll` or `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll` are the new version? If the dll are the same version and are not an improved version, setup project will not update it because they are the same as the old ones.  Especially, the `AssemblyFileVersion`. You should right-click on the dlls-->`Properties`-->`Details`. So if the file version is the same, it will not be updated. So maybe you should check this. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929914/updating-gac-dlls).